# Matching plural words in Treetop

Tags: ruby, parsing, nlp, treetop, peg

Is there a way to programmatically match plural words using Treetop. The Linguistics gem will pluralize a word, but how can that be inserted back into the parser.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'treetop'
require 'linguistics'
include Linguistics::EN
Treetop.load_from_string DATA.read

parser = RecipeParser.new

p parser.parse('cans')

__END__
grammar Recipe
   rule units
      unit &{|s| plural(s[0].text_value) }  
   end
   rule unit
      'can'
   end
end
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your full grammar, and what you're doing with it. Also: do you absolutely have to use Treetop? Could something as simple as a regexp accomplish your goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the linguistics gem can't pluralize arbitrary Treetop rule definitions—they're not strings.

Using semantic predicates your `recipe.treetop` file could define all your valid singular `unit` strings in an array, pluralize them, and then create a rule that compares the token in question to each of those pluralized units:

```
require "linguistics"

grammar Recipe
  rule units
    [a-zA-Z\-]+ &{ |u|
      Linguistics.use(:en)
      singular_units = [ "can" ]

      singular_units.
        map(&:en).
        map(&:plural).
        include?(u[0].text_value)
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was going to see if I could parse the word first and then examine its ending, but I guess that doesn't make sense for irregular plural words like (goose and geese). The only thing is, I would probably want to memoize `singular_units` since it would be used every time it hit that node.